# rake:assets precompile fails on undefined method `bytesize' for true:TrueClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, compilation, rack, assets

I'm using ruby 1.9 and when I run "rake assets:precompile" in my rails app, it fails and returned this:

`rake aborted!`

`undefined method 'bytesize' for true:TrueClass`

`~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/utils.rb:282:in 'bytesize'`

The section in the code that fails in utils.rb is this (lines 280-289):

```
if ''.respond_to?(:bytesize)
  def bytesize(string)
    string.bytesize
  end
else
  def bytesize(string)
    string.size
  end
end
module_function :bytesize
```

Line 282 is the third line down, string.bytesize.

I've found many solutions to similar problems but none were able to solve this.  Some suggestions were to change code in environments/production.rb and changing the order of gems in the Gemfile, but neither solution works for me.  Any suggestions would be very greatly appreciated.  BTW, I'm using rack v 1.4.1.

Thank you!

full trace:

```
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)  
** Execute assets:precompile  
/usr/local/bin/ruby /usr/local/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace  
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)  
** Execute assets:precompile:all  
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)  
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)  
** Execute assets:environment  
** Invoke environment (first_time)  
** Execute environment  
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)  
** Execute tmp:cache:clear  
** Execute assets:precompile:primary  
rake aborted!  
undefined method 'bytesize' for true:TrueClass  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/utils.rb:281:in 'bytesize'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:13:in 'initialize'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:241:in 'new'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:241:in 'block in build_asset'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:262:in 'circular_call_protection'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:240:in 'build_asset'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:89:in 'block in build_asset'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in 'cache_asset'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:88:in 'build_asset'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:163:in 'find_asset'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:56:in 'find_asset'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:16:in 'initialize'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:244:in 'new'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:244:in 'build_asset'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:89:in 'block in build_asset'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in 'cache_asset'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:88:in 'build_asset'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:163:in 'find_asset'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:56:in 'find_asset'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:23:in 'block in compile'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:212:in 'block in each_logical_path'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:200:in 'block (2 levels) in each_file'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:190:in 'each'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:190:in 'each_entry'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:198:in 'block in each_file'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:197:in 'each'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:197:in 'each_file'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:210:in 'each_logical_path'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:18:in 'compile'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:56:in 'internal_precompile'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:70:in 'block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in 'call'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in 'block in execute'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in 'each'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in 'execute'  
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in 'mon_synchronize'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in 'invoke_with_call_chain'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in 'invoke'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in 'block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in 'call'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in 'block in execute'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in 'each'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in 'execute'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in 'block in invoke_with_call_chain'  
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in 'mon_synchronize'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in 'invoke_with_call_chain'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in 'invoke'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in 'invoke_task'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in 'block (2 levels) in top_level'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in 'each'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in 'block in top_level'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in 'standard_exception_handling'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in 'top_level'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in 'block in run'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in 'standard_exception_handling'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in 'run'  
/usr/local/bin/rake:32:in '<main>'  
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary  
rake aborted!  
Command failed with status (1): [/usr/local/bin/ruby /usr/local/bin/rake as...]  
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/file_utils.rb:53:in 'block in create_shell_runner'  
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in 'call'  
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in 'sh'  
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in 'sh'  
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/file_utils.rb:80:in 'ruby'  
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in 'ruby'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:12:in 'ruby_rake_task'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:21:in 'invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'  
~/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in 'block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'  
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:205:in 'call'  
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:205:in 'block in execute'  
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:200:in 'each'  
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:200:in 'execute'  
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:158:in 'block in invoke_with_call_chain'  
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in 'mon_synchronize'  
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:151:in 'invoke_with_call_chain'  
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:144:in 'invoke'  
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:116:in 'invoke_task'  
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in 'block (2 levels) in top_level'  
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in 'each'  
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in 'block in top_level'  
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in 'standard_exception_handling'  
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:88:in 'top_level'  
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:66:in 'block in run'  
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in 'standard_exception_handling'  
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:63:in 'run'  
/usr/local/bin/rake:32:in '<main>'  
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

Comment: Somewhere you have a boolean where a String is expected. Is there a stack trace? The `--trace` switch to `rake` might be useful.

Comment: Full trace has been added.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What have you changed in your assets recently? Anything interesting in your asset configuration settings? You might have to move all your assets somewhere else and then add them one by one until things break, that will at least tell you which asset is the problem.

Comment: The asset behavior suggests that you have a configuration issue, perhaps some setting is a boolean when it should be a string; or perhaps something is returning `true` when it is supposed to return a string. The latter possibility certainly could be caused by an outdated `haml_assets`, what happens if you remove that gem completely?

Comment: Asset configuration is all standard.  I tried removing every single asset from the app and running the command again but get the same error, so it must not have anything to do with the assets themselves.... Edit: haml_assets wasn't a problem, I incorrectly did not see a certain part commented out

Comment: BTW, config/environments/production.rb has a line `config.assets.compile = true`... setting this to false does nothing different and adding a `config.assets.precompile = true` statement results in `undefined method 'each' for true:TrueClass`.  Statements in this file were always the same though so I am unsure if they would be problematic.

Comment: Did you end up resolving this? If so, would you mind sharing your knowledge?

Comment: No, I couldn't resolve it.  I had to skip precompiling the assets.

Comment: Can you narrow down which asset is throwing this error simply by removing folders into a completely separate temp directory and rerunning the precompile command?

Comment: Have you tried running `rake assets:clobber` before you precompile?

Comment: return 0 for that as bytesize for a string '' will be 0

Answer (score 0):

```
module DebugCall
  def bytesize(*)
    byebug # or debug call or whaterver
  end
end

TrueClass.prepend(DebugCall)
```

Then crawl up the stack and figure out what's calling and why.